# How to create routing for multi page app in react

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I want to create a multi page app in react.
I have two doubts

1st ->
For example I have 10 pages, and out of them 3 have common navbar , rest 3 have same and so on.
I am facing problem in the routing part. How should I declare them in app.js considering few have common components...rendering navbar based on path doesn't seem a good option..
I'm also thinking to create multiple files containing routes, but that also doesn't seem good to me

2nd ->
Is there a parent-child method available in react for routing? I know it is there for vue.

Comment: "rendering navbar based on path doesn't seem a good option"... Why ?

Comment: @MB_  I don't know if it's the best practice to use paths for small components or not …just want to know the best alternate

Comment: I recommend reading react-router documentation. You have a couple different ways to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Define App.js as below. In the example, you can have 2 different layouts and you can pass as many child components to each layout as you want. Now define Routes for FirstCommon and SecondCommon separately and you can adjust by your needs.  All children of firstCommon route will be like localhost:3000/web/firstCommonChild and localhost:3000/console/secondCommonChild and so on.

```
render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>    
          <Route
            path="/console"
            render={() => (
              <Layout1>
                <FirstCommon/>
            </Layout1> 
           )}
          />
          <Route
            path="/web"
            render={() => (
              <Layout2>
                <SecondCommon />
              </Layout2>
            )}
          />
          <Route component={NotFound} />
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    ) 
  }
```